# Are there any libraries in QT -for desktop- that utilize OpenStreetMap ?

Tags: qt, openstreetmap

I'm developing a small widget application in Qt and I want the widget to include a world map that utilizes OpenStreetMap. Are there any libraries in QT for desktop that can help me draw this map? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the WebKit elements would be a way to do it.

Have a look at https://www.qt.io/blog/2009/07/29/maps-with-a-magnifying-glass for how to do similar things with google maps. I'm sure a similar approach would work.

Answer (score 2):

There is a qt-based library that can do this here: https://github.com/raptorswing/MapGraphics

Answer (score 1):

You can find an example of such a widget here:

https://gitorious.org/merkaartor/main/blobs/master/src/Utils/SlippyMapWidget.cpp

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Marble](http://marble.kde.org/dev-intro.php). But, it currently supports Qt 4.x

Here is an [example code](http://techbase.kde.org/Projects/Marble/MarbleCPlusPlus) and [API reference](http://api.kde.org/stable/kdeedu-apidocs/marble/html/)